# passing data from service to fragment giving null point

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get the data from service using BroadcastReceiver and i am able to display that data in the Log but when i try to send the data using the Bundle like this

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    myReceiver = new MainActivity.MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(MediaService.MY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    super.onStart();
}

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String datapa = arg1.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED");
        String datap2 = arg1.getStringExtra("ALBUM_DATA");
        Log.d("TITLE OF SONG",datapa);
        Log.d("ALBUM",datap2);



            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Title",datapa);
            bundle.putString("album", datap2);
            Songs someFragment = new Songs();
            someFragment.setArguments(bundle);


    }

}
```

and getting the data like this

```
   String strtext = getArguments().getString("album");
        if (strtext!=null){
            textView.setText(strtext);
        }else {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(songarr.size()));
        }
 String title = getArguments().getString("Title");
    if (title!=null){
        textView.setText(title);
    }else {
        textView.setText("Total Songs");
    }
```

Error i am getting

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at beatbox.neelay.anotherbeat.Fragment.Songs.onCreateView(Songs.java:55)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                  at com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfinitePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(InfinitePagerAdapter.java:67)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2645)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2127)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1243)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1479)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Loop
```

the thing is i am playing song in service so when the user click the button the service will send the current playing song data to the activity and then from activity to the fragment and when the song is not playing it will just show the total song but when i run the app it crash saying that the null string but i am setting the else statement they what i am doing wrong ?? any hint will be helpfull .the fragment will not get the data untill the user click on the list thats the main thing .`Using the same bundle way i am able to send the data to other fragment` here the initial value is null how i can fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The error is probably before your else-if statement when trying to get the string from the arguments, in order to help you we need more code.

Comment: sir it will give null when the song is not playing

Comment: sir see the update question i added how i m getting the and receiving the data if u want i can post the fragment class also

Comment: Paste the stack trace of the crash, please.

Comment: My question is different as the initial value is null but it will change as the song start playing

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti see the update question

Comment: Check the first line of the stack trace "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)" on a null object reference". So basically, your `getArguments()` is returning `null`.

Comment: ya sir i know it will show a null value until the service starts so how can i counter this

Comment: Instead of setting it in arguments and getting it back in fragment, you can directly call fragment's methods and set text. But why creating fragment in a broadcast receiver??

Comment: thats what i am doing now thx bro

Comment: you should run asyncTask first to get service data so you can get data in background and check in onPostExecute if getArgument is not null then do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing data indirectly i used the direct way and i set like this in service

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);

    intent.putExtra("DATAPASSED", activeAudio.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("ALBUM_DATA",activeAudio.getAlbum());
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in my fragment

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(MediaService.MY_ACTION);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

}

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String datapa = arg1.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED");
        String datap2 = arg1.getStringExtra("ALBUM_DATA");
        Log.d("TITLE OF SONG", datapa);
        Log.d("ALBUM", datap2);
        textView.setText(datapa);
        textView1.setText(datap2);
    }

}
```

Hope this will help some one.

Answer (score 0):

see if your getArguments is not null first

if(getArguments() !=null )
 // then do the stuff you're doing i.e. pull strings from bundle.

Comment: tried but seem it is always null how to fix this any idea

Comment: as you mentioned in the comment "it will give null when the song is not playing" .. so you have to pass data through bundle when song is playing. rest is upto you to think

Comment: ya thats y when the song is changed or start playing it will send the data to activity and then to fragment

Comment: 'ya thats y' you have to think about how to pass data to it when played. it wont pass data on its own if you are not sending from one end to other end.

Comment: and when it is not playing it will show the arraylist size