# Pass data from service to fragment

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am starting service with download. I wish to know in the fragment that stared the downloads the progress percentage. When exiting the app and returning to this fragment (while service is still running) the percentage will continue to update.
I think I should use broadcast for this issue. Can you give me way to solve this, or example how to use broadcast in the service?

Comment: You can use `Bounded Service` and service should have to be started also. on other hand you can use a custom broadcast See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197282/how-to-send-a-custom-broadcast-action-to-receivers-in-manifest).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003020/passing-data-from-service-to-fragment-giving-null-point